# Set "value" of input fields without data-binding

Tags: vue.js

I got different input fields in a form e.g.:

```html
<input type="date" :min="today" :max="future" :id="'expenseDetail'+index" 

:name="`expense_voucher[${data.attribute}]`" :value="initForm[prop].value"

:readonly="data.render_type == 'readonly'" @input.prevent=...>
```

I want to set the value to the data in the store on pageload. For several reasons I just can't bind it to the computed property of the getter, that's why I copy the state to a reactive object called `initForm` on page-load. How would I set the input value to the contents of this object without binding the values permanently to it (like this it's jumping back to the value after changing it)?

EDIT with @input handlers (won't change the initForm at all). Just calling actions which send formData to the backend and update the store after receiving the response.

```js
setup() {
        const store = useStore();
        var typingTimout = undefined;

        var dataAvailable = ref(false);
        var initForm = ref({});

        var form = computed({
            get() {
                return pickBy(store.getters['expense/getForm'], (el) => {
                    if (el.attribute == 'due_date' || el.attribute == 'document_date' || el.attribute == 'provenance' || el.attribute == 'creditor_id' || el.attribute == 'name' || el.attribute == 'add_line_item') {
                        return el;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Detect user typing
        const checkTimeout = (event, refreshable, formAttribute, propertyName) => {
            if (typingTimout !== undefined) {
                clearTimeout(typingTimout);
            }
            typingTimout = setTimeout(updateOuter, 150, event, refreshable, formAttribute, propertyName);
        }

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- refresh outer values
        const updateOuter = (event, refreshable, formAttribute, propertyName) => {
            if (event.target.type === 'checkbox') {
                store.dispatch('expense/updateOuterValue', ({
                    refresh: refreshable,
                    formAttribute: formAttribute,
                    propertyName: propertyName,
                    value: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0
                }));
            } else {
                store.dispatch('expense/updateOuterValue', ({
                    refresh: refreshable,
                    formAttribute: formAttribute,
                    propertyName: propertyName,
                    value: event.target.value
                }));
            }
        };

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Validation controls
        const today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        const future = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 5)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Validate input values
        var invalid = computed({
            get() {
                return store.getters['expense/getValidationState'];
            }
        });

        const validate = (event, attribute, propertyName) => {
            store.dispatch('expense/validate', {
                attribute: attribute,
                propertyName: propertyName,
                value: event.target.value,
                id: event.target.id
            });
        }

        onMounted(() => {
            initForm.value = cloneDeep(form.value);
            if ((initForm.value !== undefined || (Object.keys(initForm.value).length !== 0)) && Object.getPrototypeOf(initForm.value) === Object.prototype) {
                console.log(initForm.value);
                dataAvailable.value = true;
            }
        })
```

Comment: please share the script and the `@input` event handler

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim the @input event handler just changes the data in the store. This has nothing to do with the `initForm` object and won't affect the `value`attribute.

Comment: are you using the setup hook? if yes please share its content

Comment: Ideally you should be using `v-model` bound to a computed property, which will have both a getter and a setter defined. The getter will simply fetch from whatever data store/structure you have and will populate the input field with values when necessary. The setter will dispatch the changes to the value to your VueX store. In the background, the getter should be wired to the store, so changes to the store will be reflected in the UI.

Comment: @Terry I know. I also implemented that before. But like this the values are jumping back to the values in the store after user input, cause they are updated with a delay (cause of the fetching).
I just did it as it's written in the docs. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I added the whole setup-hook as you wanted.

Comment: where did you define `prop` that you used here `:value="initForm[prop].value"`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim The inputs are inside a for-loop. and `prop` is the property of the object.

Comment: What about using the `.lazy` modifier? So that you can use [`v-model.lazy`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#lazy). AFAIK this doesn't cause your UI value to lag behind.

Comment: @Terry Is this also available for the v-bind syntax with mutations I am using right now? For v-model I'd need to use a setter at the computed property which would be kinda difficult for my use-case.

Comment: ...cause I don't manipulate the form computed prop directly, but properties of it, so the setter doesn't recognize these changes.

Comment: It is possible, but you need to debounce the method called by the `@input` binding manually (e.g. using `lodash.debounce`). See proof-of-concept here: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-cloud-topi7